# jQuery reloads javascript resources upon initial page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, performance, angularjs

I currently have a AngularJS (1.2.18) web application that uses jQuery (1.9.0) and other javascript files.

I've noticed the site loads very slowly the first time before browser caching. I discovered in order:

1. all my external javascript files load in parallel (jQuery included).
2. my script 
   `<script>
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
   </script>`
    loads to prevent jQuery from re-loading resources again.
3. a long delay, during which jQuery reloads everything in step 1 serially as seen below.

[image: jQuery reloads everything]

Why is jQuery trying to reload all my resources again?

Doesn't `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });` caches all javascript jQuery needs?

The only difference I see between `cache: false` and `cache: true` is if a timestamp gets appended to the end of the reloaded resources.  In either case, all my javascript gets reloaded again.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: 1. In a production application all these JS files should be concatenated and minified (see Gulp or Grunt for those tasks). 2. How are you loading these JS files at all? Are those SCRIPT tags in your HTML? Or is there some kind of dependency loading going on? `$.ajaxSetup` only applies to `$.ajax(...)` calls and not script tags. 3. My DevTools are set to disable cache, if yours are too, you won't see any caching while DevTools are open.

Comment: 1. Yea, this is dev environment. 2. those are SCRIPT tags in the HTML.  3. Yea mine is set to disable cache as well.  Let me try to enable caching.

Comment: @christian314159 Looks like even with the cache enabled, jQuery still seems to be reloading the scripts...

Comment: But if they are SCRIPT tags, they are meant to load like that every time. Your `$.ajaxSetup` doesn't do anything to it.

Comment: @christian314159, they do load once by the browser, but then jQuery loads them all over again for some reason.  Is that normal?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I noticed now what you mean. It happens a good while into loading that suddenly everything appears twice in the network waterfall. Is there any window.load event you are triggering? Also, did you notice that all your SCRIPT tags are outside of your body tag (they are actually all children of the HTML tag)? Maybe that could be a reason.

Comment: @christian314159, putting the script files in the head solved it!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my scripts in the index.html were neither in the `<head>` nor `<body>`.  After putting the scripts in the `<head>` everything worked.